# latex - Remove pale blu box around image-link only to a specific position

Tags: latex, hyperref

I like to make a question on the `hyperref` package of Latex. I write reports with the company's logo and I would like to add an implicit link to the official company's website, so as that if someone click on this logo can open the official web page. The problem is that this generates a bad pale blue box that is particularly ugly, therefore I would like to remove it.
I was able to remove all the box on the external link by changing the color on the specification (and setting white, perhaps there is also a way to remove) but I am trying to change only on this specific link and not all the others present other parts of the document.

Below the portion of latex code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                   
\usepackage[italian]{babel}             
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
                
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\vspace{-1 cm}
\flushleft\hspace{-1.5 cm}
\href{https://www.link.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm, keepaspectratio]{LOGO1.jpg}}
%\caption{Caption}\label{fig:logo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Do somebody knows a special tricks for doing this? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: please make a _compilable_ [mre]

Comment: I change the code to make it reproducible. It is only missing the picture but you can use a random one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the hyperref setup locally:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                   
\usepackage[italian]{babel}             
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage{hyperref}
               
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\vspace{-1 cm}
\flushleft\hspace{-1.5 cm}
{\hypersetup{hidelinks}\href{https://www.link.com/}{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}}}
%\caption{Caption}\label{fig:logo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```